# Heroku CLI commands 'pico' not recognized on Windows 10?

Tags: heroku, command-prompt

I am using the Heroku CLI in order to edit my MySQL ClearDB Server on it. Whenever I carry out the command

```
heroku config:edit --app myApplication
```

I get an error referencing ‘pico’ command.

This is what it is in it’s entirety:

```
Fetching config... done
Waiting for pico... 'pico' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: spawn pico ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/enoent.js:27:25)
```

Since I am using Windows 10, I can't directly obtain 'pico' which is for Unix systems. Don't know if there's a way around this, perhaps there is some alternative command prompt simulator I could use although don’t wanna go that route; or more favorably method of making it work by changing the default text editor for the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't fix the 'pico' problem but

> heroku config --json --app my_app

will list your config variables to the terminal. These can then be modified using the

> heroku config:set config_Key=config_Value --app my_app